# Use value from select2:opening call as input to ajax autocomplete data parameter

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, jquery-select2

I'm generating a table of results dynamically and one cell in each row contains an autocomplete. I'm using Select2 to display the autocomplete options and am populating the drop-down from ajax data and custom data unique for each row. My ajax data is coming from my Python app method and I'm using POST to send a variable back to the Python method to use to generate the custom data. Here's how this is set-up:

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data").select2({
            tags: true,
            createTag: function (params) {
                return {
                  id: params.term,
                  text: params.term,
                  newOption: true
                }
            },
            templateResult: function (data) {
                var $result = $("<span></span>");
                $result.text(data.text);
                if (data.newOption) {
                    $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
                }
                return $result;
            },
            placeholder: 'Select an option',
            maximumSelectionLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ url_for("select2Autocomplete") }}',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: "POST",
                dataType : 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({variable:myValue}),
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.resource_list
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

I've set the id of the select element to a value from my Jinja template.

```
<select onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;" id="{{ key }}" class="js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data" multiple="multiple" miriamId="{{ value }}" style="width:100%">
    <option value="{{ key }}" selected>{{ miriam_name_dict[value] }}</option>
</select>
```

Since it's dynamic I don't know what that id is for each select. I am able to get the value like this:

```
$('.js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data').on('select2:opening', function (evt) {
            myValue = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('id');
            console.log("myValue: ", myValue)
    });
```

I'd like to use myValue as the variable I send back to my python method via the data variable. Is there some way to access myValue to use in the autocomplete code?

Comment: It seems I can get the value using `$(this).attr('id')` in place of myValue in the ajax call and not use the select2:opening code snippet. Although passing `$(this).attr('id')` back to the python function gives a key error when getting the value as `jsonData = request.json['variable']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass back data to the autocomplete method for the select element the user clicked on as follows:

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data").select2({
            tags: true, //Allows for free text input of tag values
            createTag: function (params) {
                return {
                  id: params.term,
                  text: params.term,
                  newOption: true
                }
            },
            templateResult: function (data) {
                var $result = $("<span></span>");
                $result.text(data.text);
                if (data.newOption) {
                    $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
                }
                return $result;
            },
            placeholder: 'Select an option',
            maximumSelectionLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ url_for("select2Autocomplete") }}',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: "POST",
                dataType : 'json',
                data: function() {
                    var myValue = $(this).attr('id');
                    return JSON.stringify({variable: myValue})
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.resource_list
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

I was not able to use {variable: $(this).attr('id')} directly as the value for the data parameter and did need to use JSON.stringify on the value to get the value in the python method using `jsonData = request.json["variable"]`